# Не могу добавить библиотеку pygame в Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pygame

Версия python: 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (32-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:06:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Суть проблемы захожу в `Настройки проекта` -- `Настройки интерпретатора` -- жму `install` -- `вылезает следующая ошибка`:

```
Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.

Continuing With "setup.py"
Error with the "Setup" file,
perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vro43ab1\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
File "c:\users\ian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
File "c:\users\ian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 410, in expand_makefile_vars
s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Comment: 1) У меня PyCharm 2017.2.3 нет таких опций в меню и таких кнопок. Есть `File/Settings/Project/Project Interpreter`. 2) установку библиотек вы делаете не в PyCharm, а в папку питона (интерпрететора) 3) Добавьте в вопрос версию питона, например `<Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32>` 4) Я бы попробовал вам установить дистрибутив питона Anaconda, там уже много библиотек, включая pygame, установлено

Comment: Вы правильные кнопки называете, у меня добавляются все библиотеки из папки Анаконды в интерпретатор в pycharm, кроме pygame, при добавлении его все ломается.

Comment: C:\Users\Администратор\PycharmProjects\untitled>pip install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages 

Через терминал ставится, но в интерпретаторе проекта не подключается.

Comment: Поменяйте интерпретатор у проекта, там есть выпадающий список, из которого выберите анаконду